# 2D Fourier Transform of RGB Image Showing up as a White Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I'm trying to read two 'bmp' format images by `imread` function in Matlab.

For the first image, it returns a matrix of 512*512 uint8 and for the second one 512*512*3 uint8.

after doing Fourier transformation for `img2`, it shows white image. any idea?

```
img1 = imread('I1.bmp');
img2 = imread('I2.bmp');

mag1 = abs(img1);
mag2 = abs(img2);

phase1 = angle(double(img1));
phase2 = angle(double(img2));

subplot(2, 2, 1);
subimage(img1);

subplot(2, 2, 2);
subimage(img2);

FFT1 = fft2(double(img1));
FFT2 = fft2(double(img2));

subplot(2, 2, 3);
imshow(log(abs(fftshift(FFT1))), [0 10]);
colormap(gray); 
colorbar;

subplot(2, 2, 4);
imshow(log(abs(fftshift(FFT2))), [0 10]);
colormap(gray); 
colorbar;
```

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the second image is RGB and `fft2` performs the 2D FFT on *each channel separately* and returns a matix the same size as the input. When you try to display the resulting RGB image (where each channel is the FFT of each channel), it is going to show up as all white.

If you *actually* want the FFT of each channel, then you'll want to display the FFT separately for each one

```
% Display red FFT
imshow(log(abs(fftshift(FFT2(:,:,1)))), [0 10]);
```

Your other option is to convert the image to a grayscale image *before* taking the FFT

```
img2 = rgb2gray(img2);
FF2 = ff2(img2);
imshow(log(abs(fftshift(FFT2(:,:,1)))), [0 10]);
```

[image]